# pgAdmin 4 v3 Auto Indent not working

Tags: windows, auto-indent, pgadmin-4

Since upgrading to 4.3, Auto Indent is not working (working in a Query Tool tab). When pressing enter at the end of a line of code, the cursor appears at a random position on the next line (sometimes right at the end) and not at the correct indentation position. This is very frustrating, as I have to click at the beginning of the line and indent correctly myself for every new line.

I have tried Chrome and Edge with no difference. I have changed the Tab Size and Use Spaces Options without any luck. I am using Windows 10 Pro.

Anyone else with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE!!!

---

### This issue is fixed in pgAdmin 4 Version 4.3!

Thank you pgAdmin Team!

Note:  This is still an issue up through pgAdmin 4 version 4.2
       Updated:  Feb 19, 2109
       :(

/*
    Issue:

```
(Tested on Windows Server 2012 R2, Chrome and Firefox, pgAdmin 4 3.2)

Using nested functions in a variable assignment, or just in a SQL statement 
causes multiple tabs to be added when hitting enter for a new line anywhere 
later in your code. 

If you uncomment the first line with nested functions (below), all
carriage returns lower in the code create new lines with
many unwanted tabs. 

Uncomment the line below and hit enter at the end of the line, 
or before another line of code.
```

*/

/*

x := upper(substr('uncomment to test this.  Hit enter after the semicolon.', 13));

*/

/*
    My workaround is to unnest the functions and use multiple statements.
    Note:  Be sure the offending line above is commented out.
*/

x := substr('uncomment to test this.  Hit enter after after the semicolon.', 13);

x := upper(x);

Answer (score 0):

Have tried your suggestion and it does work. But it does seem odd that we have to comment out the entire offending line (i.e. with the nested text) to make this work. I haven't had this issue with other editors. For example, entering the same text in SQL Developer as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE deptno IN (SELECT deptno FROM departments
                 WHERE loc = 'CHICAGO');
```

Pressing enter will place the cursor under the 2nd WHERE (same as Postgres). I clear the tabs with Shift+Tab to column 1, and going forward I am fine. Each new line, cursor is at the beginning. This doesn't work with Postgres.

I am still new to a lot of this.  Thank you for sharing.